# Relay working at 3.3V for RPi?

Tags: rpi.gpio

I need to use my RPi to control a relay which switches on/off an electrical circuit.

I got a relay board but it seems that works only when used at 5V.

I'm a noob so please go a bit easy on me.:P

What relay boards are available which work on  3.3V or what other methods can I use to get this to work?

Comment: Liable to be closed for shopping question... off limits per the FAQ.  You should be able to reword it to work though...  A quick google should turn up something though...

Comment: Do you have the schematic? It can probably be made to work

Comment: Just use a normal transistor connected to the 5V line to switch the relay. See e.g. http://www.susa.net/wordpress/2012/06/raspberry-pi-relay-using-gpio/

Answer (score 1):

I am also a RasPi newcomer, but:

I had a similar issue myself connecting a 5V RF receiver to the RasPi's 3.3V GPIO input and I was helped in the [Adafruit Industries forums](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=41120&start=0).

Adafruit sells [logic-level](https://www.adafruit.com/products/735) [converters](https://www.adafruit.com/products/395) from 5V to 3.3V, they might help you.

Answer (score -1):

Quite an old question but if anyone is looking for the same thing here's an answer.

Use a transistor to switch your relay on/off.
Make a search in Google on "Transistor switch relay".